# Django to conf a url that contains a number

Tags: python, django, url

I want to make a function to judge a number from url is odd or even. Here is the code about judge:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
import datetime

def judge(reqest, number):
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404() 
    if number % 2 == 0:
        html = "<html><body>%d is even!</body></html>" % (number)
    else:
        html = "<html><body>%d is odd!</body></html>" % (number)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Now, I am stuck in the `url.py`, I don't know whether a edit like this will work:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #(r'^$', time_now),
   (r'^number/(.+)$', judge), # we just want the number in the url, not more or less
)
```

but I want to handle empty input too, but the page gives that `"Nothing input"` every time I try this:

```
def judge(reqest, number):
    if number is None:
        html = "nothing input!"
        return HttpResponse(html)
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404() 
    if number % 2 == 0:
        html = "<html><body>%d is even!</body></html>" % (number)
    else:
        html = "<html><body>%d is odd!</body></html>" % (number)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two urls like this

urls.py

```
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #(r'^$', time_now),
   (r'^number/(.+)/$', judge),
   (r'^number/$', judge),
)
```

Set default value

views.py

```
def judge(reqest, number=None):
    ...
```

Comment: err... i'm not quite sure if my regex knowledge applies here, but wouldn't a single `(r'^number/(.*)/$', judge)` do the trick?